# django: tatsypie REST framework dehydrate issue

Tags: django, tastypie

In my model i have amount field i want sum the amount.

Following the my model ; **model.py**

```
class EntityLoan(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    amount = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey('StaticStatus',db_column='status',related_name='+status+')
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_modified_by = models.ForeignKey('EntityUser', db_column='last_modified_by')
    last_modified_date = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'entity_loan'
```

The Following is my tastypie resource code **api.py**

```
 class LoanResource(ModelResource): 

            class Meta:
                queryset = EntityLoan.objects.all()
                resource_name = 'entityloan'
                fields = ['amount']
                filtering = {
                    'amount': ALL,

                }       
            def determine_format(self, request):
                return 'application/json'
            def dehydrate(self,bundle):
                items= bundle.obj.amount.all()
                bundle.data['item_count']=items.Sum('amount')
                bundle.data['items'] = [i.to_dict() for i in items]
                return bundle
```

But i am getting error

> error_message": "'float' object has no attribute 'all'",

Comment: you're trying to get all() of a field, but that doesn't make sense. For which items are you trying to aggregate? The total amount for all the EntityLoan model objects?

Comment: i am trying to take the sum of amount field data. like how we does in django `EntityLoan.objects.annotate(Sum('amount'))`